# Find length of a list of lists

Tags: prolog, nested-lists

I wrote a predicate which should calculate the length of a list:

```
 my_length([],0).
 my_length([_|L],N) :- my_length(L,N1), N is N1 + 1.
```

Can anyone help in adjusting this so that it will take a list of lists and output the total number of elements in the list of lists?

Comment: Just make another predicate, similar to this, but instead of adding 1, add the result of my_length.

Comment: If you can use existing Prolog predicates (if they're in your Prolog library) you could also just do `my_length(L, N) :- flatten(L, F), length(F, N).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most of what you need: add a rule that computes the length of a list of lists that passes the head on to `my_length`:

```
my_length_lol([], 0).
my_length_lol([H|L],N) :- my_length(H,Add), my_length_lol(L,N1), N is N1 + Add.
```

As you can see, `my_length_lol` ("lol" stands for "List of Lists") is a near exact copy of `my_length`. The only difference is that it does not ignore list head, and uses `my_length` rule to compute the length of a sublist.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/uZAzlR)

Comment: Using variable names like `Xs` and `Xss` would help

Answer (score 1):

In this answer we use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) in combination with [Prolog lambda expressions](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord).

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
```

We define the predicate `lists_length/2` like this:

```
lists_length(Xss,N) :-
   foldl(\Xs^N0^N2^(length(Xs,N1),N2 is N0+N1), Xss, 0,N).
```

Sample query:

```
?- lists_length([[a,b,c],[],[d,e]], N).
N = 5.
```

Comment: Minor remark on conventions: For differences it is quite helpful to mark them by **removing** separating spaces. Thus `foldl( ... , 0,L)`

Answer (score 1):

I am still not the biggest fan of `foldl/4` and thus I find it much more natural to state:

```
xss_length(Xss, N) :-
   maplist(length,Xss, Ns),
   list_sum(Ns, N).
```

Still, this does not terminate for `Xss = [_,_], xss_length(Xss, 2)`. But it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

Both the solution posted @dasblinkenlight and the original code in the question can be made **tail-recursive** by using accumulators, which would allow running in **constant space**:

```
my_length(List, Length) :-
    my_length(List, 0, Length).

my_length([], Length, Length).
my_length([_| Tail], Length0, Length) :-
    Length1 is Length0 + 1,
    my_length(Tail, Length1, Length).

my_length_lol(Lists, TotalLength) :-
    my_length_lol(Lists, 0, TotalLength).

my_length_lol([List| Lists], TotalLength0, TotalLength) :-
    my_length(List, Length),
    TotalLength1 is TotalLength0 + Length,
    my_length_lol(Lists, TotalLength1, TotalLength).
```